Interface property to be the type of another property in typescript
Suppose I have a typescript interface like so:
interface MyInterface {
  property: string;
  setProperty: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;

  property2: number;
  setProperty2: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>;

  property3: boolean;
  setProperty3: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

Is there any way for me to reduce duplication by doing something like this?
interface MyInterface {
  property: string;
  setProperty: Dispatch<SetStateAction<typeof property>>;

  property2: number;
  setProperty2: Dispatch<SetStateAction<typeof property2>>;

  property3: boolean;
  setProperty3: Dispatch<SetStateAction<typeof property3>>;
}

This fails as ts says

Cannot find name property

Is there some alternate syntax that I can use to achieve this?

@InSync thank you for your suggestion, it is similar albeit the syntax is ugly :(

I would use a mapped type that adds a setter for each property.
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

type AddSetters<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends string ? `set${Capitalize<K>}` : never]: SetStateAction<Dispatch<T[K]>>;
}

type Foo = {property1: string, property2: number}

type FooWithSetters = Foo & AddSetters<Foo>


This is almost good, except if my Foo contains some things that are state props and some that are not :(

You can reference the interface properties like this:
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";


interface MyInterface {
  property: string;
  setProperty: Dispatch<SetStateAction<MyInterface['property']>>;

  property2: number;
  setProperty2: Dispatch<SetStateAction<MyInterface['property2']>>;

  property3: boolean;
  setProperty3: Dispatch<SetStateAction<MyInterface['property3']>>;
}

Playground

OLD
I can't answer the self-referencing interface directly, but there are two approaches you could use to couple the state and setter types:
Predefine types for each state and reference them:
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

type PropStates = {
  property: string,
  property2: number,
  property3: boolean
}

interface MyInterface {
  property: PropStates['property'];
  setProperty: Dispatch<SetStateAction<PropStates['property']>>;

  property2: PropStates['property2'];
  setProperty2: Dispatch<SetStateAction<PropStates['property2']>>;

  property3: PropStates['property3'];
  setProperty3: Dispatch<SetStateAction<PropStates['property3']>>;
}

The second, funner, way is to make a utility type that creates the state and setter types for you:
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

type Pascal<T extends string> = T extends `${infer I}${infer G}`
  ? `${Uppercase<I>}${G}`
  : never;

type StateAndSetter<N extends string, T> = {[x in N]: T} &
  { [x in `set${Pascal<N>}`]: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>};

type Props = {NonStateProp: number} & 
  StateAndSetter<"property", string> &
  StateAndSetter<"property2", number> &
  StateAndSetter<"property3", boolean>


let a: Props;

a.   // <- Check autocomplete options and their types (in the playground)

Playground
If you want to use the interface syntax, you could use extends

Very creating approach (the second one). I guess the only issue I have with this one is that if I have 5-10 state vars per component this will look somewhat ugly-ish and I almost prefer my current setup even though it is more manual to set up.

@zaitsman Looks like it's possible for the interface to self-reference, I updated my answer. I quickly skimmed the duplicate source and this approach isn't in there (I think).
